# Programmatically Send Mail to MailHog

Tags: email, go

I'm trying to catch e-mails using MailHog in Go. However, their API doesn't demonstrate how to send an email to it in Go itself. I was wondering if anyone has some sample on how to.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use my library [Gomail](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail/):

```
package main

import "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"

func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", "from@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("To", "to@example.com")
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Hello!")
    m.SetBody("text/plain", "What's up?")

    d := gomail.NewPlainDialer("smtp.example.com", 587, "user", "123456")
    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Tried by run mail hog in my machine. This is the code
{

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add("glitson@gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("priyesh@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Email using Gmail";
            string Body = "Hello";
            mail.Body = Body;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "Localhost"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
            smtp.Port = 1025;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
            ("username", "password");

            //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
            //smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
```

}